# C# Convert String to DateTime (AM : PM)

Tags: c#, string, sql-server-2008, datetime

There is a textbox in my application which is used to input time (Hour and Minute) with AM PM.
In the database the relevant field for that textbox is "Times" which hold the datatype as DateTime

```
string times = "06:45 AM";
```

To DateTime for Sql-Server (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`)

How do I convert input form textbox to database?

Comment: So what day that time is for?

Comment: current time.(today as he/she input)

Comment: @azalikaEriya, please tick Rufus L answer so more people will find the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("06:45 AM");
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Comment: Correct answer, just to add - that'll give today's date with that time, so if he wants another date he needs to specify it.

Comment: There is no guarantee for OP's `CurrentCulture` have `HH:mm tt` as a standard date and time format. Would be better to specify an `IFormatProvider` for example `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: @azalikaEriya what "didn't work" mean? Did it output "I DON'T WORK" on the screen?

Comment: the screen say "ERROR System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated. " @zerkms

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you're using so we can try to help?

Answer (score 2):

Sql Server's [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) type always have date and time part.

If you wanna insert this hour part with `Today`'s date, you can directly parse this `string` to `Datetime` and you can insert this `DateTime` to your database. Like;

```
string times = "06:45 AM";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(times, "HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    //dt will be 15/01/2015 06:45:00 and insert this DateTime directly
}
```

Comment: in my database datetime format is like 2015-01-15 06:06:06.000.
is it okey if I use yours ?

Comment: @azalikaEriya A `DateTime` doesn't have _any_ implicit format. It just have date and time values. `String` representation of a `DateTime` can have a format. Yes, it is okey to use this `dt` value to insert your `datetime` typed column.

Comment: then, on insert statement i just call dt ?

Comment: @azalikaEriya Yes, directly pass this `dt` value to your [parameterized](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) insert statement.

Comment: @azalikaEriya _is not work_ is not an helpful explanation. What is _now working_ exactly? If you have a different question, you should ask it a separate one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   TimeSpan theTime = DateTime.Parse("06:45 AM").TimeOfDay;
```