# C# Convert String to Date Time Whereas string has AM : PM formate

Tags: c#, datetime, converters

I have string time. lets say '06:35 PM'. I want to convert the string to DateTime.
The date must be current time(the day as they input the time).

I did

```
string times = endTime;
DateTime dt;
(DateTime.TryParseExact(times, "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
```

But it didn't works. it make a null value. because when I try to put the result on label, the label did not show anything. and also I have been try

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("06:45 AM");
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

But it didn't works too and it makes an error.

> ERROR System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated. "

How do I convert it ?

Comment: The code you have included has nothing to do with sql, are you sure this is the part of code that is producing the error?

Comment: Please post the correct code. This is SQL Server complaining yet you have posted C# code that has nothing to do with SQL (Server).

Comment: Is `endTime` a `"06:45 AM"`?

Comment: The DateTime code pasted has nothing to do the exception. It is talking about a SqlException. Paste in the code where database is being called. For a parameterised query or stored procedure, check the values that are being passed through. Somewhere you are sending a parameter to a SQL datetime column that contains an invalid value.

Comment: yes, endTime = "06:45 AM"
so, do you mean this error cause by sql statement ?
I have some value to insert in database. if I do not insert the endTime value, it'll fine. the value is inserted. but if I do insert the endTime on sql statemen. it do not insert the data. the row on sql is not added. @MurrayFoxcroft

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Convert String to DateTime (AM : PM)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958164/c-sharp-convert-string-to-datetime-am-pm)

Comment: Added an answer below with more detail to get you pointed in the right direction. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are passing the string "06:45 AM" to the database and this is not a valid entry since the DB does not know how to store it, hence the exception.

Looking a bit further, in your **first example**, YYYY should be lowercase yyyy. YYYY will not parse properly correctly in to a date format.

Considering the **second example** you have two options:

1) When writing to the database, make sure you pass a valid date, e.g. below. You may need to try a few formats to match up to what your DB expects but it will need a full date and time.

```
var date = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt}", DateTime.Parse("06:45 AM"));
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

2) Use a full DateTime approach using the correct SQL parameter type. This looks like a good explanation covering a few gotchas. [Using DateTime in a SqlParameter for Stored Procedure, format error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425870/using-datetime-in-a-sqlparameter-for-stored-procedure-format-error)

Answer (score 1):

If day doesn't matter, you can use following

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("06:45 AM", new[] {"h:mm tt"}, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine(date);
    Console.WriteLine(date.TimeOfDay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code will solve your issue;

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(06, 45, 0);
dt = dt.Date + ts;
```

To convert string to DateTime format, use the below code;

```
string date = "01/08/2008";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```